# DropdownList com valores únicos MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Minha classe `Galeria` possuí uma chave estrangeira com `Album` pois existe uma relação 1-n e cada foto no item `Galeria` possuí respectivamente um `Album`.
Dado isso, no CMS que criei dou a possibilidade do usuário relacionar uma foto com um Album na hora do upload. Para isso, minha View está assim:

```
<div class="editor-label">
   Cursos @Html.DropDownList("Album", ViewData["Cursos"] as SelectList)
</div>
```

E meu Controller:

```
AlbumAplicacao bdAlbum;
   bdAlbum = AlbumAplicacaoConstrutor.AlbumAplicacaoEF();
   var list = new SelectList(bdAlbum.ListarTodos().OrderByDescending(x => x.Nome), "ID", "Nome");
   ViewData["Cursos"] = list;
```

Meu Dominio:

```
public class CONGRESSO_Galeria
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public string Foto { get; set; }

    public virtual CONGRESSO_Album CONGRESSO_Album { get; set; }

}
```

Meu problema é que estou obtendo diversos valores idênticos na Dropdown. Tentei usar `Trim()` e filtrar Utilizando o `Distinct()` mas não obtive sucesso.

Notei que o problema foi gerado pois na hora de gravar o item, estou gravando novamente um Album. Vou corrigir isso, porém já houve o cadastro de centenas de itens e graças a isso, preciso dar um jeito de mudar a exibição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rafael.

Tente isso:

```
[Controller]
     var list = new SelectList(bdAlbum.ListarTodos().OrderByDescending(x => x.Nome).GroupBy(x => x.Nome.ToLower().Trim()).Select(y => y.First()) , "ID", "Nome");
```

Desse jeito irá agrupar todos os valores iguais.

O correto é evitar que valores duplicados sejam inseridos no seu banco.

Comment: Diego, não funcionou. A ordem do `OrderBy` e do `GroupBy` estava errada, mesmo corrigindo e aplicando :             `var list = new SelectList(bdAlbum.ListarTodos().OrderByDescending(x => x.Nome).GroupBy(x => x.Nome.ToLower().Trim()), "ID", "Nome");` não obtive sucesso

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa, editei a resposta. Tinha me esquecido do .Select().

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado.